# Correct sort order with a 1 byte index that rolls over

Tags: arrays, sorting, stack, fifo

In an embedded system I am limited to using an array index that is only 1 byte long (0-255, then rolls back to 0). The array keeps getting additional entries continuously, but the total length of the array is fixed and much smaller than 255 (say 5). The old values simply get overwritten, or "popped" (FIFO stack).

Usually, the sort order for most-recent first (or last) is simply a numerical sort of the array indices (7,8,9,10,11 OR 17,18,19,20,21  OR 124,125,126,127,128 etc).

Except when then index reaches 255, and it rolls over. Now, the values look like

253, 254, 255, 0, 1 OR 254, 255, 0, 1, 2

In such cases the simple numerical order (0, 1, 253, 254, 255) is not a most-recent first (or last) sort.

What is an elegant way to find the correct sort order in such cases?

Comment: From Honza's response, once the rollover was detected, I treat all numbers as 1-byte 2's complement. Now 254 becomes -2, 255 becomes -1, while 1 remains 1, 2 remains 2. The index order is the recency order!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for the "rolling" case (integer overflow) somehow and compensate (perform a correction).

Checking for possible overflow:

1. There is an element in the array bigger than, let's say, 240
2. You keep `added` and `removed` boolean flags with the array. You initialize them to the same value. When an item with index 0 is added to the array, you flip `added`. When an item with index 255 is removed from the array, you flip `removed`. You have an overflow if their values are equal.

Compensating:

1. Type-cast your values to `signed char` (or `int8_t`). Will not work for indexes around 127-128, but since your array is small, you should be safe.
2. Create a temporary array and subtract or add 128 to shift the values to the middle of the value range, where they can be compared. The same caveat applies.

Answer (score 0):

The code could keep track of a 1 byte starting index and a 1 byte ending index. Using two's complement math on the 1 byte indices, (ending index) - (starting index) == array size. Wrap around won't be an issue.